# Android: Listening to activity onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-activity

So, on Android,
How can I listen to/subscribe to an Activity `onDestroy()` method? I have a shared object/class/service that can be accessed and created through multiple activities but it needs to know when the caller activity is destroyed.

I can't modify the caller activities code, but I have a reference to the particular activity that is calling my class.

So someActivity -> Creates my object
Object needs to know when that activity closes.

Comment: Check Application class documentation... I'm pretty sure that it contains suitable method...

Comment: You don't.  You could call that object from onDestroy of your activity, but that's about all.  I question why you need this-  it sounds like you have something mis-scoped.  Why do you need to know about the Context that created it, and only that?

Comment: The thing is that multiple activities (of different types) can create/call this object/service. I only know the activity context and nothing else. I can't modify all these activities in my project, but the object needs to know when the activity dies so it can do some cleanup work. So I was wondering if I could create a listener and hookup to the Activity.onDestroy() method since i have a reference to the activity.

Comment: "I can't modify all these activities in my project"--If they are in your project, why can't you modify them? At present there is nothing built into Android that allows you to observe these lifecycle events. You would have to have the Activities call your Service in onDestroy() to let you know that cleanup needs to occur.

Comment: It is unrealistic to expect all activities and new/future activities to know of the existence of this object. It would be best if this object could manage itself independently of the activities that use it.

Comment: as I wrote ... registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to do something in the object you created using your activity, but somehow, if your activity is closed. Then your object will crash if it try to access getActivity().

Assume your activity class name someActivity and your object is a fragment. Fragment provide you to use getActivity. If the object you created not a fragment, then you probably has to find a way access it.

```
someActivity activity = (someActivity) getActivity();
        if (activity != null && !activity.isFinishing()) {
              //do your action here to prevent the app crashes.
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this is not quite what I'm looking for. A more concise example is an activity signs up/subscribes to my object/service. I have no control whatsoever over this activities code. 

The service/object needs to know when the activity is destroyed so that it can unsubscribe it. So I need some kind of listener for the onDestroy() for any activity that subscribes to it.

Comment: @emcv I need the exact same thing to listen for activity's onDestroy(). I have a service binding component and I bind to service inside the component, and whichever activity uses it, I need a callback to understand the activity is destroying so that I can unbind service in my component.